Youtube videos stutter When I use ViVi share screen feature to mirror my device
I have an issue with Vivi. When I play YouTube video on my laptop and share it on TV with ViVi the screen-sharing feature, the video plays smoothly on my device. However, the video starts dragging once I share my screen using Vivi on the TV. Why is this happening?
I have tried basic troublshooting like checking bandwidths and testing on different devices but problem is still there.
